# What does <number>%<number> mean in a CSS length, eg 100%25

Tags: html, css, svg

I came across some code today where the author declared a length as `<numeric value>%<numeric value>`

CSS: `width: 100%25;`
HTML/SVG: `width="100%25"`

I have been writing CSS for years and I have never seen a length declared like this. It seems to work in HTML, SVG and CSS.

Is it some form of shorthand? What does it mean? I have tried searching for answers, but the nature of the topic made it hard to find something.

[Original code](https://gist.github.com/notpushkin/77e428462be6c266832aaef6fce54150):

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 900 900' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <foreignObject width='100%25' height='100%25'>
        <div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
            <style>
                .c{
                    display:flex;
                    align-items:center;
                    justify-content:center;
                    margin:0;
                    width:100%25;
                    height:900px
                }
                .b{
                    width:33.33%25;
                    height:33.33%25;
                    background:red
                }
            </style>
        <div class='c'>
            <div class='b'/>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: I makes sense, but why are they just now adding `mod()` in `CSS Values and Units Module Level 4` if this already exists? https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#funcdef-mod

Comment: Also, wouldn't the remainder of 100 divided by 25 be 0? That wouldn't make sense as it is used in the original code.

Comment: What makes you think this is not just a typo? At least this is no valid unit according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: I think you should ask the author because this seems to be invalid

Comment: I'm assuming this was used on purpose as it's in there several times. The tweet where I saw it was retweeted by [Lea Verou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90826/lea-verou), so I'm thinking it has some credibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are looking at contains percent-encoded `%` characters which (as yet) remain undecoded.

If you percent-encode:

### %

you get:

### %25

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: This is it! The author explained it to me as well https://twitter.com/notpushk_in/status/1371111289360121862

Comment: I didn't think of the difference it made that it originally was a data URI. very stupid of me.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself, @oelna. I only picked it up _precisely_ because I did some work back in December involving SVGs encoded as Data URLs.